# Generate random numbers until every digit [0, 9] is generated

Tags: perl, random, scripting

I want to make an experiment where I create a list of many lists of randomly generated sequences that all contain every digit 0 to 9 inclusive, that is, the generation function is to generate random numbers and place them in a list of integers while there is at least 1 digit not found in the list.

The intention for the experiment is to try to make some generalizations about things like expected number # of digits in such a function, how long can a sequence get(can my program loop indefinitely and never find that last digit?), and other interesting things(for me).

I am using PERL for the experiment.

The idea seemed simple at first, I sat down, created a list, and figured I can just make a loop that runs an arbitrary amount of times (I decided to choose 100 times), which calls a function generate_sequence(input: none, output: list of numbers that contains at least 1 of every digit) and adds it to the list.

I quickly realized that I struggle cleanly specifying what it means, pragmatically, to generate a list of numbers that contains one of every digit.

My original attempt was to make a list of digits(0..9), and as I generate numbers, I would search the list for that digit if it is in the list, and remove it. This way, it would generate numbers until the list of digits "still needed" is empty. This approach seems unappealing and can involve a lot of redundant tasks such as checking whether the digit generated is in the list of digits needed every single time a number is generated...

Is there a more elegant solution to such a problem? I am really unhappy with the way I am approaching the function.

**In general, I need a function F that accepts nothing, and returns a list of randomly generated numbers that contains every digit 1..9, that is, it stops as soon as every digit from 1 to 9 inclusive is generated.**

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: `random.shuffle(list(range(10)))`

Comment: Thanks, will that only be a shuffled list of 0..9? because my experiment involves generating UNTIL all digits are hit, not just shuffle 0..9, that is [0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9] is possible.

Comment: What does "really unhappy" mean for you?

Comment: @Wolf seems like a very clumsy way to approach the problem, I feel like there is a more elegant way to approach it that does not need as many checks, un-needed additional lists(for checking what is still needed to be found). I merely mean that this approach does not feel correct/I am not satisfied with it.

Comment: I'd search for a map (hash/dict) and count the keys. Not sure if this is possible in the languages you address...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the problem is if you 'roll randomly' you don't actually know how many iterations you're going to need - in theory it could be infinite.

If you're doing it in `perl` you're probably much better off using the `List::Util` module and `shuffle` - feed it a list of elements you want to shuffle.

E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; 
use warnings;

use List::Util qw( shuffle );

my @shuffled = shuffle ( 0..9 );

print @shuffled;
```

You could reproduce this quite easily, but why bother when `List::Util` is core as of 5.7.3

However it does sound like you're trying to generate a list, that *might* contain repeats, until you hit a terminate condition.

I'm not entirely sure why, but that would be best done using a hash, and counting occurences. (And terminate when your 'keys' is complete).

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; 
use warnings;

my %seen;
my @list_of_numbers;

while ( keys %seen < 10 ) {
   my $gen = int rand ( 10 );
   $seen{$gen}++; 
   push ( @list_of_numbers, $gen );
}

print @list_of_numbers;
```

Note - there's actually an extremely small chance of this rolling extremely long sequences, because of the nature of 'random' - it means in theory you might have a very long 'streak' of not rolling a 6.

For bonus points in `%seen` you have a frequency spread of your generated numbers.

Comment: Thanks! So from my understanding, the cleanest solution to doing this, is through using dictionary and fill it until it has 10 unique keys.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "clean" really. If the code is clear what it's doing, and the algorithm isn't absurdly inefficient, then that is what matters. Everything else is premature optimisation - let the compilers worry about that, and if it actually matters, get a code profiler out to see where you need to worry.

Comment: Could use an array instead of a hash. The following should be a little faster (and way easier to implement in C): `my @nums;
my @seen;
my $remaining = 10;
while (!$remaining) {
   push @nums, int rand 10;
   --$remaining if !$seen[$nums[-1]]++;
}`

Comment: @ikegami Shouldn't it be `while ($remaining)`?

Comment: @Benjamin W., woops, yeah

Answer (score 1):

A python implementation:

```
from random import randint

s = set(range(10))
def f():
    result = []
    t = set()
    while 1:
        n = randint(0, 9)
        result.append(n)
        t.add(n)
        if t == s:
             return result
```

For example:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(len(f()))
   ....:     
20
34
69
22
23
25
20
29
30
32
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (python):

```
import random
nums = []
while any([ i not in set(nums) for i in range(1,11)]):
    nums.append(random.randrange(1, 11, 1))
```

or more specific to what you are trying to do:

```
import random

lengths = []
for i in range(1000):
    nums = []
    while any([ i not in set(nums) for i in set(range(1,11))]):
        nums.append(random.randrange(1, 11, 1))
    lengths.append(len(nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach counts the iterations needed to fill a dictionary of digits:

```
import random

c = 0
d = dict()
while len(d.keys()) <10:
    d[random.randint(0,9)] = 1
    c += 1

print c
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrote this before you switched to just Perl...

```
from random import randrange

def F():
    todo = set(range(10))
    nums = []
    while todo:
        r = randrange(10)
        nums.append(r)
        todo.discard(r)
    return nums

>>> F()
[8, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 3, 9, 3, 4, 7, 4, 7, 5, 0, 9, 5, 5, 6]
```

Another:

```
def F():
    done = 0
    nums = []
    while done < 1023:
        r = randrange(10)
        nums.append(r)
        done |= 1 << r
    return nums
```

Comment: its fine, i wanted ideas/solutions in any script, I was just suggested to stick to one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible Perl implementation that counts the iterations needed to fill a hash with the 10 digts:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $count = 0;
my %dict = ();

while (scalar keys %dict < 10) {
    $dict{int(rand(10))} = 1;
    $count ++;
}

print $count;
```

(see [online demo](https://ideone.com/ArYQNU))

Answer (score 0):

In clojure (though probably not the most elegant):

```
(loop [n []
       s (set (range 0 10))]
  (if (= s (set n))
    n
    (recur (conj n (rand-int 10)) s)))
```

Sample output:

```
user=> (loop [n [] s (set (range 0 10))] (if (= s (set n)) n (recur (conj n (rand-int 10)) s)))
[0 6 2 8 5 2 0 0 9 3 0 3 0 1 7 5 0 4]
user=> (loop [n [] s (set (range 0 10))] (if (= s (set n)) n (recur (conj n (rand-int 10)) s)))
[2 1 7 7 3 2 8 8 4 7 5 0 1 3 0 3 0 4 0 0 3 7 3 4 5 8 1 3 8 5 3 5 5 9 4 0 2 1 2 7 8 3 9 7 8 6]
user=> (loop [n [] s (set (range 0 10))] (if (= s (set n)) n (recur (conj n (rand-int 10)) s)))
[7 1 8 3 1 1 0 6 8 4 9 7 0 0 2 7 4 0 1 1 8 8 4 3 9 8 4 2 8 3 2 8 4 6 0 9 9 7 2 3 0 3 0 4 2 4 0 5]
user=> (loop [n [] s (set (range 0 10))] (if (= s (set n)) n (recur (conj n (rand-int 10)) s)))
[9 1 9 0 9 5 3 0 3 8 4 0 1 6 3 0 1 8 0 3 8 3 5 4 3 9 8 8 8 8 2 2 8 9 9 3 9 2 5 1 1 3 4 6 3 1 4 0 2 6 7]
user=> (loop [n [] s (set (range 0 10))] (if (= s (set n)) n (recur (conj n (rand-int 10)) s)))
[4 1 5 5 5 5 2 2 5 5 3 1 5 3 5 1 4 2 4 2 3 1 4 7 1 9 3 8 0 8 4 0 9 3 4 9 9 1 8 8 0 6]
user=> (loop [n [] s (set (range 0 10))] (if (= s (set n)) n (recur (conj n (rand-int 10)) s)))
[0 4 0 9 1 8 4 8 6 6 6 9 8 4 9 0 9 3 3 7 6 1 4 3 8 1 1 4 9 5 1 4 1 2]
user=>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Clojure, I am keeping track of both the random list and the existing values, thus avoiding a search on the growing list.

```
    (defn random-list [ up-to ]
     (loop [ n [] tries [] ]
      (if (> (count n) (dec up-to))
        tries
        (let [i (rand-int up-to) n-tries (conj tries i)]
          (if (some #{i} n )
            (recur n n-tries)
            (recur (conj n i) n-tries))))))
```

We can define similar functions:

```
    (defn random-list-to-10 []
      (random-list 10))

    (random-list-to-10)
    ; [3 6 9 0 8 0 5 7 3 8 1 8 4 3 4 2]
```

We can also take only a few random elements:

```
    (take 5 (random-list 10))
    ; (6 1 0 9 5)
```